# Does this result hold for harmonic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on $D = D_1(0)$ and continuous on the closure.  Suppose $f(e^{i \theta}) = 0$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$, then $f$ is identically zero.  Does this result still hold when $f$ is real-valued and harmonic on $D$?

My proof goes as follows for $f$ analytic: it is clear that $f(iz)$ is zero for $|z| = 1$ in the lower right quarter circle, $f(-z) = 0$ for $z$ in the lower left, etc. so $$g(z) := f(z)f(iz)f(-z)f(-iz)$$ is zero on $\partial D$.  The maximal modulus principle implies that $g$ is identically zero on $D$.  Thus for each $0 \leq r \leq 1$, and any $|z_r| = 1$, one of the numbers $f(i^k z_r)$ is zero for $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$.  This shows that $f$ has uncountably many zeros, so $f = 0$.

The proof I gave doesn't seem to extend to $f$ being harmonic, for example nonconstant harmonic functions can take the value $0$ on a set with a limit point.  So I kind of expect there to be a nonzero harmonic function $u$ for which $u(e^{i \theta}) = 0$ for $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, such a function $u$ exists. Let $\theta\mapsto f(e^{i\theta})$ be any continuous function from $[0,2\pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, not identically zero. It can be zero on part of the circle, but not the whole circle. Let $u:\bar D\to\mathbb{R}$ be the solution to Dirichlet's problem with boundary values $f$. This $u$ is harmonic on $D$ and continuous on $\bar D$, so it  is not identically zero.

Comment: However if $u$ is real and harmonic on $D(0,R)$ for some $R>1,$ and $u=0$ on the arc mentioned, then $u\equiv 0.$

Comment: @zhw Why is that?

Comment: One proof would be to use real analyticity: $t \to u(e^{it})$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R},$ hence if $u$ vanishes on an arc, it is the zero function. Then we have $u=0$ on the circle, hence inside the circle by the maximum principle, hence in $D(0,R).$

Comment: @zhw I'm curious to know why that function is real analytic. Off the top of my head, it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: Plausibility argument: Suppose $u$ is real and harmonic in $ U = \{x+iy: y > -1\}.$ Then $u$ is the real part of a holomorphic $f$ in $U.$ Now $f$ is representable by power series near each point of $U,$ hence $f$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}\subset U.$ Thus $u$ is real analytic on $\mathbb {R}.$ That's not a proof for the circle, but it's suggestive. If you really want the proof for the circle, I can scare it up for you.

Comment: That's OK, you don't need to scare up a full proof. But let me give you my implausibility argument: The level sets of non-constant harmonic functions give all sorts of curves. Why the particular shape "circular arc" can never occur puzzles me. But I don't know that much about harmonic functions, to be honest.